# Selecting students who have not made any payment in a given period (term)

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `students` and `payments`.

`students` has the columns:

```
first_name
last_name
student_id
class_name
```

`payments` table has the columns:

```
full_name
student_id
term
session
amount_paid
class_fee
```

The details of every student is in the `students` table, but only those who have made either full or part payment enters the `payments` table. I have written a query to select those who have paid.

The question now is how to write a query that will select those in a particular class that have made no payment at all in a given period (term).

Comment: SELECT p.*,s.*
FROM payments p
LEFT JOIN students
  ON s.student_id=p.student_id
     where p.amount_paid <= 0 and p.term = 'yourcondition'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a `JOIN` to select those who *have* paid.  That will work because there are matching rows in both tables.  To find those who *have not* paid, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`.  It will give you `NULL` if rows do not match.

```
SELECT students.*
FROM students
LEFT JOIN payments ON students.student_id = payments.student_id
    AND term = 'whatever'
WHERE amount_paid IS NULL
```

<sub>(Note: the `term = 'whatever'` needs to be in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE`)</sub>

You can also do this using a subquery and the `NOT EXISTS` clause.  `NOT EXISTS` will return true if the subquery returns zero rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT amount_paid
    FROM payments
    WHERE students.student_id = payments.student_id
        AND term = 'whatever'
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rocket for your quick response, but what about the class of the student? I want to query a given class, say class1. Should I add AND class='$class1' at the end?

Comment: @OponjousJoe: `class` is part of the `students` table, yes?  If so, then yeah that should work.

Comment: I appreciate, but I want to query a class say class1,within a session say 2016/2017 and in a term say first_term. I appreciate any further help please.

Comment: You should be able to add `and sesssion = 'whatever'` after the `term = 'whatever'` in the query for that to work.  For class, which table is that value stored in?

Comment: Class is in payments table

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work well. It returns everything in the students table. See My code: $unpaid = "SELECT students.*
FROM students
LEFT JOIN payments ON students.student_id = payments.student_id
    AND term = '$term1' AND class='$class1' AND session='$session1'
WHERE amount_paid IS NULL"; $run_unpaid = mysqli_query($can, $unpaid); while(row_unpaid=mysqli_fetch_array($run_unpaid); {$name = $row_unpaid['first_name']; $unpaid_class = $row_unpaid['class_nane']; <tr><td><?php echo $name;  ?></td> <td><?php echo $unpaid_class; ?></td></tr>} Please what did I do wrong?

Comment: Does it work properly with the `NOT EXISTS` version?  Try adding the extra clauses to the `WHERE` inside the parenthesis.

Comment: The two versions do not work well. They are returning the difference in the the two tables, i.e, names of students in the students table that never ever entered the payments table. This happens even though I try to use AND to filter the session, term and class. Note that session, term and class are in the payments table.  What I want is a query that in a given period say 'first_term' of 'session_1' will return names of all students in a say 'class _1' who have not paid anything. Please I still need further help. Thanks

Comment: Hello Rocket, your query has finally worked for me, although I amended it.

Comment: The working query is SELECT * FROM students WHERE class='whatever' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT amount_paid FROM payments WHERE students.student_id = payments.student_id AND session='whatever' AND term='whatever')